# C++ Calculate age from string

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and I need to include in my program a function to calculate the age of someone from a School Code which looks like this: MAPA29088809
Age being the 29/08/88...
I think I need to use a substring or something but I dont know how to get started... Can anyone help me please?

All I have is a way to calculate it from an age that is given...

```
int main()
{
    system("TITLE how old are you?");
    int yearnow,yearthen,monthnow,monththen,age1,age2;
    cout<<"\t\t\tEnter the current year and month \n\t\t\t(eg. 1997, enter,7,enter):\n";
    cin>>yearnow;
    cin>>monthnow;
    cout<<"Enter your birthyear and month: \n";
    cin>>yearthen;
    cin>>monththen;
    if(monththen >12 || monththen<1)
        return 1;
    if(monththen > monthnow){
         age1=yearnow-yearthen-1;
         age2=(12-monththen) + monthnow;
    }else{
         age1=yearnow-yearthen;
         age2=12-monththen;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\tYou are "<<age1<<" year and "<<age2<<" moth old";
    system("pause>>void");
}
```

Comment: You can use the `substr` method of `std::string` to extract out substrings for the year, month, and day.

Comment: substring is indeed the way to go. Check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/ for examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly simple problem. You have an string that contains pairs of valuable information.

```
char* inputData = "MAPA29088809";
```

Assuming the first four characters are the identifier for how to parse this data:

```
char* format = new char[5]; // Extra character for the null terminator
memset( format, 0, 5 );
memcpy( format, inputData, 4 );

if( strcmp( format, "MAPA" ) == 0 ) // then your input data is in MAPA format
```

Then for the other pieces of data, based on the given format, can be pulled out fairly easily.

```
char* day = new char[3];
memset( day, 0, 3 );
memcpy( day, format + 4, 2 );

char* month = new char[3];
memset( month, 0, 3 );
memcpy( month, format + 6, 2 );

char* year = new char[3];
memset( year, 0, 3 );
memcpy( year, format + 8, 2 );

char* whateverThatLastOneIs = new char[3];
memset( whateverThatLastOneIs, 0, 3 );
memcpy( whateverThatLastOneIs, format + 10, 2 );
```

And you can use `atoi` to convert them into integers.

```
int iDay = atoi(day);
int iMonth = atoi(month);
int iYear = atoi(year);
int iWhatever = atoi(whateverThatLastOneIs);
```

This is a quick-and-dirty way to do this. Using std::string and substr might be better. But this is fundamentally what you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I might try it that way, I only need those characters though: 290888  which is the birth date and calculate from todays date to get age...

Comment: Okay. Then you can skip the processing of the MAPA part and jump right to pulling the data off.

Comment: I got it working, how can I compare these numbers 29(day) 08(month) 88(year) with todays date to get age ?

Comment: @DrewSalesse: Look up time and date functions in your favorite C++ reference book.

Comment: @DrewSalesse: The easiest method is to convert the date formats into some lower level unit like days.  Subtract the days, then convert the value into years to get the age.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) method of `std::string` to extract out the year, month, and day as strings. You can then use [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) (or [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) if you have access to a C++11 compiler) to convert the strings to ints.

Comment: Pre-C++11 I would prefer using `std::stringstream` for conversion.